# Does std::unique_lock::try_lock_until() busy wait?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, locking

I'm thinking of using the following code:

```
auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex, std::defer_lock);
if(lock.try_lock_until(now + std::chrono::milliseconds(15))
{
    // swap some buffer pointers...
    lock.unlock();
}
```

However, it's not clear to me from the documentation if `try_lock_until()` is implemented as a busy wait or if the thread will yield/sleep in between tries (which is my desired behavior). Is this the best way to query a lock while minimizing thread resource usage?

Comment: I don't think the standard requires any particular implementation, but, in at least the VS version of the library, it doesn't spin.

Comment: Side note: You need a `unique_lock<timed_mutex>` to use `try_lock_until`. Also, `try_lock_for`  seems to be more suitable to your use case.

Comment: @T.C. thanks, I hadn't picked up on that.

Answer (score 3):

The [CppReference page for `std::unique_lock::try_lock_until`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/try_lock_until) indeed only states it "Blocks until specified `timeout_time` has been reached or the lock is acquired". This is not just a shortcoming of the website though. The standard (I used [the November 2014 working draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf)) carefully steers clear of specifying whether a `thread` has to `yield` while blocking on any kind of `mutex`, talking only about acquiring ownership.

For `std::mutex`, for instance, section 30.4.1.2.1 states

> If one thread owns a `mutex` object, attempts by another thread to acquire ownership of that object will fail (for `try_lock()`) or block (for `lock()`) until the owning thread has released ownership with a call to unlock().

No mention of scheduling or `yield`ing is made at all, though.

Furthermore, even if it did mention `yield` explicitly, that wouldn't help that much, as `this_thread::yield` (section 30.3.2) merely "Offers the implementation the opportunity to reschedule".

[CppReference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/yield) makes this more concrete, stating

> The exact behavior of this function depends on the implementation, in particular on the mechanics of the OS scheduler in use and the state of the system. For example, a first-in-first-out realtime scheduler (SCHED_FIFO in Linux) would suspend the current thread and put it on the back of the queue of the same-priority threads that are ready to run (and if there are no other threads at the same priority, yield has no effect).

So I'm afraid the question of how `try_lock_until` is implemented *in C++* cannot be answered. Perhaps you can ask a new question targeting a specific platform. For your second question ("Is this the best way to query a lock while minimizing thread resource usage?") the answer is yes, the best option your platform offers should be invoked using this API (though, as T.C. commented, `try_lock_for` seems like a better fit).

Comment: My sincerest apologies, I'm not sure how I managed to misread it so badly. I've updated my answer to, well, to answer your actual question.